# PictureBox Intesect

Tags: c#, collision-detection, picturebox

I'm working on a simple 2d game with pictureboxes but I´m struggling with collision detection.

I've been looking around and came up with this:

```
     public bool ObstacleHit()
    {
        if (pbPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pbObstacle1.Bounds))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

which is called here:

```
            if (e.KeyChar == 'w')
            {
                    ObstacleHit();
                    if(ObstacleHit() == true)
                    {
                        moveUp();     
                    } 
            }
```

but this ain't working.

Comment: on a different subject, your function could be  `public bool ObstacleHit(){ return !pbPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pbObstacle1.Bounds) }`

Comment: please don't put "[C#]" in your title. Just leave it in the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, see if this works. For various key selection rather than the if-statement, you may as well implement the use of a switch-case statement.

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
        {
                bool hit = ObstacleHit();

                if(hit == true)
                {
                    moveUp();     
                } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to check `KeyChar`

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.W)  
{
     ObstacleHit();      // unnecessary call of method here        
     if(ObstacleHit())   // need not to compare a bool value  
      {
           moveUp();     
      } 

}
```